# Javascript code snippet different behavior than jsfiddle

Tags: support

First, I'm not sure if this should be on SO or meta, but...

When I run the code snippet below, I get one alert instead of two.  If I run the same code on jsFiddle or jsbin, I get two alerts as expected.

Is this a flaw in the way snippets are handled on SO?

```js
alert(1);
test = Number(localStorage.test) || 0;
alert(2);
```

Comment: Did you look in your error console? In Chrome, I get `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag` when running the snippet. This is presumably a deliberate choice, though that's certainly open for clarification. The error thrown by this prevents the second alert from running.

Comment: Nope, using iPad -- not a real excuse, should have thought of turning the console on...